# Tag rename request [fire-emblem] -> [fire-emblem-blazing-blade]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The description for the tag [fire-emblem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem) mentions that this is for a specific game named **[Fire Emblem : The Blazing Blade](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_The_Blazing_Blade)** in the Fire Emblem game series. The tag name is misleading because it could be confused with the name of the series itself. Therefore please rename it to [fire-emblem-blazing-blade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-blazing-blade).

Comment: What's the reason for creating a tag synonym, as opposed to just editing the question to have the tag specific to that game, and editing the [tag:fire-emblem] tag wiki?

Comment: Well then we have to create a new tag for fire-emblem-blazing-blade. Whatever seems easier for the mods. I am not requesting it to be a synonym, instead I am requesting it to be renamed.

Comment: It's not about what's easier, it's about what has a better outcome. And for the record, creating a tag requires 300 rep, while creating a tag synonym requires 2500 rep and agreement from 3 or 4 other users who also have 2500 rep (or moderator action). And I think a tag rename without creating a synonym can only be done by a mod.

Comment: What do you mean by better outcome?

Comment: A tag synonym leaves the original in place as a kind of signpost so that you can use it when tagging a question, and it automatically gets mapped to the other one. This is useful when there are multiple common names for the same thing (e.g. [star-wars-the-old-republic] and [swtor]). But it has the potential to be confusing when the original is the name for the whole series, because people might use it when they mean the series as a whole or any other game in the series. A tag rename isn't a separate thing, it's just creating a synonym for an existing widely-used tag.

Comment: It is possible to avoid leaving that signpost by creating the synonym to retag all existing questions, and then deleting the synonym, but then it's essentially just a mass retag. Doing a mass retag of one question is excessive and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I made the synonym [fire-emblem-the-blazing-blade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-the-blazing-blade) for the original tag [fire-emblem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem).  If anyone uses the synonym, the post will automatically be tagged with [fire-emblem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem).